# SQL Server Column saving FileName as varchar need to remove the directory from the string

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have a column in my table called FileName not realizing what I had done was I also saved the directory for instance a value is \test-srv-1\Uploads\Test.jpg I want to run an update statement that will remove the directory and just leave the Test.jpg. I have a 1000 rows to update. Is there an easy way of doing this in SQL server using a update statement? Now that the server is changing it makes for a maintenance nightmare. Ugh I wish I had caught this a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is pretty easy using [REVERSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx).

You can do something like this to test out how the rename will look:

```
select right(MyColumn, charindex('\', reverse(MyColumn)) - 1)
from MyTable
where charindex(MyColumn, '\') > 0
```

If you are satisfied with the output, do:

```
update MyTable
set MyColumn = right(MyColumn, charindex('\', reverse(MyColumn)) - 1)
where charindex(MyColumn, '\') > 0
```